# How stop (cancel) a download using TIdHTTP and keep connection

Tags: delphi-xe, indy10

There is a good answer on half of my question: [How stop (cancel) a download using TIdHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922787/)

But if I use `Abort`, then sometimes the `GET` request will still continue to run.

If I use `Disconnect()` then the next `GET` request will establish a new connection with the server and spend time for that. I run `GET` requests to an HTTPS server. The HTTPS protocol consumes about 50% time just for establishing connections.

How can I stop a `GET` request and keep the connection for the next request? How can I sweep garbage and reset state?

I think I need to change:

```
 try
    try
      ReadBytes(LBuf, i, False);
    except
      on E: Exception do begin

        // ADD THIS!
        if (E is EAbort) then
        begin
          //Set some flags
          //ClearBuffers 
          raise;
        end

        // RLebeau - ReadFromSource() inside of ReadBytes()
        // could have filled the InputBuffer with more bytes
        // than actually requested, so don't extract too
        // many bytes here...

        i := IndyMin(i, FInputBuffer.Size);
        FInputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(LBuf, i, False);
        if (E is EIdConnClosedGracefully) and AReadUntilDisconnect then begin
          Break;
        end else begin                                                                                     
          raise;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: I had read, I have tested and I had hope what in 7 years something changed.

Comment: **exceptions raised will make it stop running, and will propagate back into your code**

I see it in debugger.   FInputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(LBuf, i, False) in except section stills call onWork  and works until requesttimeout.

Comment: When an exception is raised, bytes that are already in the `InputBuffer` because they were read from the socket prior to the exception being raised are still extracted into the caller's target. Indy will not go back and read more bytes from the socket, the exception is re-raised instead. Timeout handling is done if an exception is raised. But either this, this is a side matter from your question. I already answered your question - you CAN'T leave the connection open if an exception is raised, period. You simply don't know the state of the connection/communication at that point.

Comment: BTW, the code you have quoted was re-written several years ago.  You should upgrade to an up-to-date version of Indy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your claim, *ALL* exceptions raised will make `TIdHTTP` stop running the current request/response cycle, and will propagate the exception back into your code for handling <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: except in the specific case where an exception is raised when a remote disconnect is performed, and a remote disconnect is expected to indicate the end of the response. `TIdHTTP` handles that condition internally and stops reading without re-raising the exception.

My [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922787/#comment63109533_6923250) on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922787/) still applies here:

> **You can't abort a request midway and expect to leave the connection open**, you don't know what state you are leaving the socket in or what data has already been transmitted. **There is no way to clear an HTTP connection and leave it open for a new request.** The only sane thing to do is close the connection.

If you are worried about re-establishing new HTTPS connections taking too long, there are technologies to address that, such as Fast TCP Open and TLS session reuse.  But Indy does not implement those features at this time.  There are open tickets for them:

[#213: Add support for OpenSSL session reuse](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/213)

[#263: Add support for TCP Fast Open socket option](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/263)